# How to remove border of img for banners only in a Wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

I like the Erudite Wordpress theme. However I don't want border for certain type of img, i.e. banners. I still want border for other images in the media library.

How can I edit the style.css to remove border only for banners?

For example, in this page [here](http://www.clomputing.com/?p=17).

The image is:

```
<img class="noborder" src="http://www.clomputing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/available-on-appstore.png" width="280" height="80" />
```

And I tried the following in the *style.css*:

```
img.noborder { border:none; }
```

but the border is still there.

The full style.css is:

```
.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.alignleft {
    float: left;
}

.alignright {
    float: right; 
}

img.noborder { border:none; }
```

Comment: Try this a img.noborder { border:none; } and you didn't add class for img tag.

Comment: I reviewed your stylesheet and img.noborder doesn't seem to be included.

Comment: @Dan I edit the stylesheet via `Appearance` > `Editor` tag. How can I make Wordpress include my edited style.css?

Comment: @ohho, sorry for the late response. By the sounds of it there is a disconnect between your WP style editor & the stylesheet. By the look of your comment it sounds as though you have fixed your own problem. All the best =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unknown reason, `style.css` is not included. I have to ftp into the site and edit `erudite.css` directly:

```
.entry-content img.no-border {border:0 none; padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this css using `important` in your style:

```
.noborder {
    border: medium none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The border is given to parent div so even if you give border:none; property to your img tag that won't work.You should remove the border from class entry-content i.e parent div and instead add border to the image where you want the border.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case @fahad.kazi - see the following screen shot: http://postimage.org/image/e8sbpruhl/full/

Comment: I should explain it to you .entry-content img is given border and it will style every img in that div.Its called css specificity.

Comment: Also I found that .entry-content a is giver border-bottom.